# How to align two columns in an equation next to each other with no space?

Tags: equations, align

I want to align two columns in an equation next to each other with no space. I am using the following code.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
    N(vw)=N(s_iuw)=N(s_i(uw))
    & = N(s_i) & \Delta \; &  s_iN(uw)s_i \\
    & = N(s_i) & \Delta \; & s_iN(u)s_i \; \Delta \; s_iuN(w)u^{-1}s_i \\
    & = N(v)   & \Delta \; & s_iuN(w)(s_iu)^{-1} \\ 
    & = N(v)   & \Delta \; & vN(w)v^{-1}.
    \end{aligned}
    \qedhere
\end{equation*}
```

but there's a space between the two columns as below.

[image]

How do I get rid of the space?

Comment: See the `alignedat` env, note that it takes a mandatory argument which in this case would be 2

Comment: Is `\Delta` to be considered as a binary operation symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from all `\;` commands, your Delta should be considered as a binary operation symbol.

Use `alignedat`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newcommand{\bDelta}{\mathbin{\Delta}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
N(vw)=N(s_iuw)=N(s_i(uw))
  & = N(s_i) && \bDelta s_iN(uw)s_i \\
  & = N(s_i) && \bDelta s_iN(u)s_i \bDelta s_iuN(w)u^{-1}s_i \\
  & = N(v)   && \bDelta s_iuN(w)(s_iu)^{-1} \\
  & = N(v)   && \bDelta vN(w)v^{-1}.
\end{alignedat}\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: heading shows 2 answers but there is only one answer  -- going the virus way

Comment: @jsbibra there are two deleted answers